# ClassCastException while extracting data from List

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, classcastexception, pojo

This is my XML file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<logExtract>
    <configuration>
        <splunk>
            <splunkHost>localhost</splunkHost>
            <userName>abcd</userName>
            <password>1234</password>
            <port>8214</port>
        </splunk>
        <tsdb>
            <tsdbHost>localhsot</tsdbHost>
            <port>4242</port>
        </tsdb>
    </configuration>
    <dataPart>
        <ingestion id="abc">
            <tsdbElements>
                <metricname>linecount0</metricname>
                <tags>splunk_server0</tags>
            </tsdbElements>
            <splunkQuery>
                <Query>index=_internal source=*/splunkd_access.log |head 0000</Query>
            </splunkQuery>
        </ingestion>
        <ingestion id="xyz">
            <tsdbElements>
                <metricname>linecount</metricname>
                <tags>splunk_server</tags>
            </tsdbElements>
            <splunkQuery>
                <query>index=_internal source=*/splunkd_access.log |head 1000</query>
            </splunkQuery>
        </ingestion>
        <ingestion id="def">
            <tsdbElements>
                <metricname>linecount2</metricname>
                <tags>splunk_server2</tags>
            </tsdbElements>
            <splunkQuery>
                <query>index=_internal source=*/splunkd_access.log |head 2000</query>
            </splunkQuery>
        </ingestion>
    </dataPart>
</logExtract>
```

I have used JAXB and created POJO class structure for it.

For `Ingestion` element this is my POJO class structure.

```
private String id;

private List<TsdbElements> TsdbElements;

private List<SplunkQuery> SplunkQuery;

@XmlAttribute
public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement
public List<TsdbElements> getTsdbElements ()
{
    return TsdbElements;
}

public void setTsdbElements (List<TsdbElements> TsdbElements)
{
    this.TsdbElements = TsdbElements;
}

@XmlElement
public List<SplunkQuery> getSplunkQuery ()
{
    return SplunkQuery;
}

public void setSplunkQuery (List<SplunkQuery> SplunkQuery)
{
    this.SplunkQuery = SplunkQuery;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", TsdbElements = "+TsdbElements+", SplunkQuery = "+SplunkQuery+"]";
}
```

Here is the Problem :-

When I try to extract Objects of `ingestion` I get error

> (java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.jaxb.xmlfile.Ingestio)  java.lang.ClassCastException

at line below comment.

```
String fileName = "Query.xml";
File file = new File(fileName);

//JAXB Parsing - Unmarshling XML File
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLData.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

LogExtract logExtract = (LogExtract) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

Configuration config = logExtract.getConfiguration();

Splunk spluknData = config.getSplunk();

Tsdb tsdbData = config.getTsdb();

DataPart dataPart = logExtract.getDataPart();

List<Ingestion> ingestionData = dataPart.getIngestion();

//Here I get Error 
List<TsdbElements> tsdbElementsData = ((Ingestion) ingestionData).getTsdbElements();

//Here I get Error     
List<SplunkQuery> splunkQueryData = ((Ingestion) ingestionData).getSplunkQuery();

System.out.println(spluknData.getSplunkHost() + "  " + spluknData.getUserName() + "  " + spluknData.getPassword() + "  " +spluknData.getPort());

System.out.println(tsdbData.getTsdbHost() + "  " + tsdbData.getPort());

for (SplunkQuery splunkQuery : splunkQueryData) {
    System.out.println(splunkQuery.getQuery());
}

for (TsdbElements tsdbElements : tsdbElementsData) {
    System.out.println(tsdbElements.getMetricname() + "  " + tsdbElements.getTags());
}
```

So what am I missing?

**EDIT:-** (After answer given by @Sanj)

How to save `tsdbElement` data using `for` loop and then access them again out of `for` loop? Any Idea? Because its only saving last XML data, not all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Ingestion> ingestionData = dataPart.getIngestion();

//Here I get Error 
List<TsdbElements> tsdbElementsData = ((Ingestion) ingestionData).getTsdbElements();
```

The error is stating that ingestionData is a type List, and you are trying to cast it to the Ingestion class.

Looking at your XML, you have a list of of these elements

```
    <ingestion id="abc">
        <tsdbElements>
            <metricname>linecount0</metricname>
            <tags>splunk_server0</tags>
        </tsdbElements>
        <splunkQuery>
            <Query>index=_internal source=*/splunkd_access.log |head 0000</Query>
        </splunkQuery>
    </ingestion>
```

So you just need to iterate the list ingestionData to get the tsdbElements. Something like

```
// instantiate the tsdbElementsData list
List<TsdbElements> tsdbElementsData = new ArrayList<>(TsdbElements)

for (Ingestion ingestion: ingestionData)
{
    // get the elements
    tsdbElements = ingestion.getTsdbElements();

    // do some with the elements, e,g add to a another list
    tsdbElementsData.add(tsdbElements);
}
```

To iterate through the tsdbElementsData list, it is just another loop

```
for (TsdbElements tsdbElements: tsdbElementsData)
{
    // ... do something with tsdbElements
}
```

Note that the foreach loop above, is the same a writing

```
for (int i = 0; i < tsdbElementsData.size(); i++)
{
    TsdbElements tsdbElements = tsdbElementsData.get(i);
    // ... do something with tsdbElements
}
```

Comment: How to save `tsdbElement` data using `for` loop and then access them again out of `for` loop? Any Idea? Because its only saving last XML data, not all of them

Comment: added some further code to iterate through the tsdbElementsData list